# Shell function in c programming just like in visual basic

Tags: c, vb.net

Can anyone tell me what is the code in c programming for the shell function just like in visual basic it is:

```
Shell("C:\WINDOWS\CALC.EXE", 1)
```

Thank You

Comment: simplest of all would be [`system`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the VB function is just a simplfied wrapper around Windows API [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea).

The equivalent C code would be something like:

```
#include <windows.h>

ShellExecute(NULL, 
             NULL, 
             "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\CALC.EXE",
             NULL,
             NULL,
             SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `system()` function in C.

An example:

```
system("calc.exe");
```

**Edit:** You need to use an escape sequence for representing a backslash, because it itself represents the starting point of defining an esc. sequence (e.g. `\n`), use `\\` wherever you need to append `\`. For example:

```
system("My\\Long\\Long\\Path\\program.exe");
```

Comment: It opens the calculator app, but does not open the directory that i asked the program to open.
```
system("F:\Programs for Dev C++\MatrixCode.exe");
```
The program says the following :
'F:Programs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AjayKokill \ inside a C string is reserved for escape sequences. For this reason, you must always use \\ when you want an actual backslash.

Comment: In C++, `\ ` is a string escape character. You need to use `\\ ` instead.

Comment: @Lundin
Ya, ok, got it